# Encoding unicode as a csv string

Tags: java, python, csv, unicode

I would like to encode this string as a python string.

**Example of String:**
*"abc\nbcd"* unicode String

```
p=subprocess.Popen([path],stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
p.stdin.write('strings\nstrings')
p.stdin.flush()
output = p.stdout.readline() #output reads from Java
```

I am piping this output to a java program.

My java program would be reading input via `Scanner(System.in)`

Java Program

```
Scanner scan = New Scanner(System.in, "UTF-8");
PrintStream out = new PrintStream(System.out, True, "UTF-8");
System.setOut(out);
while (true)
{
    while(in.hasNextLine())
    {
        //do processing
        //splitting this up. The output would be an array
        //method to combine the array elements to a string.
        System.out.println(output);
    }
}
```

This issue will arise if i have lots of files which have to be processed sequentially. What would happen would be that the buffer will be filled and there will be a deadlock arising.

So Basically what i am looking for is a solution in such a way that "abc\ncde" could be considered as one line instead of 2 separate lines.

Well bascially i am trying to tokenize some unicode string.

***Workflow***

Read string from file(can have multiple strings). Pass them to the Java engine to tokenize. Return the tokenized string as a single string delimited by "\k"(arbitary delimitation). Using a string builder to combine the tokenized tokens and splitting them up again in python.

Heres the problem. When reading from stdout, not all the tokens get flushed out of the stream and some is left in stdout leading to a deadlock situation.

Hence, my code.

`p.stdin.write(txt)` hangs as the stream is full.

Comment: This is not clear. '\n' is the newline character, which is the end of a line. How do you suggest that two lines will be considered as one?

Comment: How does your program know when to stop reading `stdin`? The pipe is never closed, so `hasNextLine()` will wait for more input.

Comment: @Realskeptic Yes. There could be a possibility i would like to process multiple strings at once.

Comment: Why call `System.setOut(out)`? Just use `out` instead of `System.out` in the loop.

Comment: @Andreas This pipe will never be closed. It will only close if my python script exits

Comment: @aceminer Then you Java program will not exit until your python script does. I hope your python script is short-lived.

Comment: Computers are very simple minded. If you ask them to read a line, they will read characters up to the next newline character. Can you suggest a method that a computer can understand, in order to distinguish your `\n` from any other `\n`? Is there anything special about it?

Comment: @RealSkeptic My Java engine can only accept a single string. Regardless of how it is encoded but it only can accept one input into stdin

Comment: @aceminer But *how* will it know where the *end* of that input is? --- Hint: `flush` does not mark the end of anything.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something here. Can you edit your question, show what your output is, and what you *expect* your output to be?

Comment: @RealSkeptic Confusion often arises when a question title says "encoding unicode" and "csv", but question text has no "comma-separated-values" and is all about `\n`. *<sighs>*

Comment: Ah, I think you forgot to add an `\n` at the end of the line, @aceminer . The `write` method in python doesn't do that automatically for you.